# EasyDriver stepper motor through sysfs not moving

Tags: gpio, sysfs

I'm trying to activate a stepper motor using easydriver from here https://www.schmalzhaus.com/EasyDriver/Examples/EasyDriverExamples.html using sysfs and C, but it doesn't move.

[image]

I connected my circuit like that
but with a raspberry pi, code is here https://pastebin.com/xWPZ31Ju
someone can please have a look and tell me if there's something obviously wrong or if my code seems correct?

I wired `gpio23` to `dir` and `gpio24` to `step` and connected an external power source to my motor.

Comment: Have you tried that with an LED or something so you can rule out wiring etc. with the motor?

Comment: Photo of **your** setup plus a listing of the software **you are** using.